# Display time for specific event in simulink/stateflow

Tags: time, simulation, simulink

I am trying to get the time at which a specific condition in my simulation occurs. Specifically, in my simulink model I am comparing two inputs and I need to save to the workspace the time at which they equal each other. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following 2 steps:

1. Inside a Triggered Subsystem, put a Clock block feeding directly into a To Workspace block.  Make the subsystem *rising edge* triggered.
2. Outside the Triggered Subsystem, compare your two signals, and feed the comparison into the trigger port.

The times at which the comparison is true will get written (as a vector) to the specified workspace variable.

Comment: Thank you! The diagnostic viewer is displaying an error related to my clock block... It says: clock has sample time [0,0]. Only constant or inherited sample times are allowed in triggered subsystems. I am unsure what this means..

Comment: You can feed any block into the To Workspace block as long as the variable you create also has time saved with it -- Structure With Time for example -- so just feed a constant into it instead of the clock.

Comment: Uh! Ok, great advise thank you! Do you know if there is also a way to have the time at which the comparison holds true as an output of the triggered subsystem?

Comment: Feed a clock as an input to the Triggered Subsystem; within the subsystem have an Inport connected directly to an Outport.  The outport will have the value of the clock each time a trigger occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for sharing your expertise!